# How to set text to label with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button, label, set

I want to set text to label with jQuery after clicking on button. I wrote code and it works, but after I set text in my label, label return his old state. Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicWebApplication.WebForm2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>

        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function f() 
            {
                $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("hello");  
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <p></p>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="f();"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If your button is causing a postback then the changes will be lost after the page has reloaded. Try this -

```
function f() 
        {
            $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("hello"); 
            return false;  
        }
```

Comment: What behaviour do you see? Does the label change then the page refreshes and the change has gone?

Comment: Label changes and the change has gone without page refresh.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. the label change then the page refreshes and the change has gone

Comment: If you change 'OnClientClick="f();"' to be 'OnClientClick="f();return false;"' does that make any difference? Do you have any other jQuery functions linked to the page?

Comment: Yes - it stops the page posting back. Your jQuery code was updating the label but clicking the button caused the page to post the form data back to itself so your jQuery change was lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `text` method to set the text

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="return f();"/>

function f() 
    {
        $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("hello"); 
        return false;  
    }
```

Comment: Is your page posting to the server on button click?

Comment: In that case you should `return false` from the function to stop the page to submit.

Comment: No, You can see all my code. I didn't write nothing in file .css

Answer (score 2):

Labels do not maintain viewstate.  The server will not post that information back to the server.  You can try explicitly enabling the ViewState on your Label, but if that doesn't work, you will have to store that value in a hidden field.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Not clear, what is it to store that value in a hidden field. Can you write code?

Comment: I have already found solution.  'OnClientClick="f();"' to be 'OnClientClick="f();return false;

Answer (score 2):

I would use this,

```
$('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').text("hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return f();"/>

function f() 
{
    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("hello"); 
    return false;  
}
```

OR

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function(){
    $('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("hello");
    return false; 
   });
});
```